# page.collection() is empty despite having child pages

Tags: twig, grav

I'm using Masonry theme and trying to show all posts in a collection. Masonry does this normally and I had it working previously, but now page.collection is empty despite having pages. I've made sure that the children are routable and visible. I even reinstalled the theme, to no avail. Any ideas? At this point I haven't actually modified any code that would affect that page logic relating to the collections.

At the top of the file is:

```
{% set collection = page.collection() %}
```

I used

```
{{dump(collection)}}
```

But nothing shows up. What gives?

Comment: Have you defined the collection in your page's header? See https://learn.getgrav.org/content/collections#example-collection-definition. `page.collection()` depends on your page's header, so re-install the theme or not doesn't make any differences, the problem seems coming from your page's content.

Comment: @HungTran You're right on that, thanks for pointing it out. I must have missed something when I was first working with the theme, because I don't recall having to add anything of the sort to the page header. 

That docs page example shows "@self.children" for the content items. A short while after I posted this question I discovered that setting the collection variable to page.children accomplishes the same effect, without having to add extra header content.

Answer (score 2):

I changed page.collection to page.children instead. It accomplishes the same thing without having to add extra header content on my page. Thanks to HungTran for pointing out the correct way though.

Answer (score 0):

If `collection()` is indeed a method, then you would use this in Twig instead:

```
{% set collection = page.collection %}
```

Can you try that. I'm not certain it will work, but let us know the result.

Comment: That was the theme default in the top with collection(), yes. I tried page.collection on its own as well. As per HungTran's comment, the proper solution was to include the children item into my page headers. However I found an alternative that doesn't require that.